# bootstrap popover open only from one link

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem when opening popover from different links.

*Here my javascript code:*

```
$("#popover").popover({
    html : true, 
    content: function() {
      var type = $(this).data("type");
      alert(type);
      return $("#content").html();
    },
    title: function() {
      return $("#title").html();
    }
});
```

*And here my two links in order to open the popover from them:*

```
<a href="#" id="popover" data-type="1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="popover" data-type="2">Link 2</a>
```

*popover contents:*

```
<div id="content" class="hidden">
  Contents
</div>
<div id="title" class="hidden">
  Title
</div>
```

**I have this problem:** I can open popover only from LINK 1, when i click on LINK 2 nothing happened.

Comment: Not sure if this will be the cause of the issue, but something I noticed is that IDs need to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".popover").popover({
    html : true, 
    content: function() {
      var type = $(this).data("type");
      alert(type);
      return $("#content").html();
    },
    title: function() {
      return $("#title").html();
    }
});


<a href="#" class="popover" data-type="1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="popover" data-type="2">Link 2</a>
```

Not right to repeat id in html tags